# PyQt: How can I quit a QDialog?

Tags: pyqt, quit, qdialog

I've build a QDialog Widget. My problem is, I can't quit the QDialog. 
If I press one of the buttons, then the QDialog is only set to "hide".
Here is a little part of the code. It is executable. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe one of you can tell me.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class MyClass(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # init
        # ------------------------------------------------
        self.setMinimumWidth(600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Select Dingsda")
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layoutWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.liste = []
        # widgets and layouts
        # ------------------------------------------------

        tempLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.connect(self.cancelButton, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.cancel)
        self.addSelectedButton = QPushButton("Add Selected")
        self.connect(self.addSelectedButton, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.addSelected)
        tempLayout.addStretch()
        tempLayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)
        tempLayout.addWidget(self.addSelectedButton)
        self.layout.addLayout(tempLayout)

        # test-data
        # ------------------------------------------------
    # methods
    # ------------------------------------------------

    def cancel(self):
        self.close()

    def addSelected(self):
        self.liste = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        self.accept()


    def exec_(self):
        if QDialog.exec_(self) == QDialog.Accepted:
            return  self.liste
        else:
            return []

def test():    
    app = QApplication([""])
    form = MyClass()
    i = form.exec_()
    print i
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know python at all but it looks like the dialog is the only window for your app. You may want to try invoking the dialog with `form.show_()` instead of `form.exec_()`. The latter is normally used to display the dialog modally over a parent window.

Comment: Oh damn. That could be the answer. At the moment it is the only window, because I'm still working on it and testing it. 
Now I feel kind of stupid. 
Anyway thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To terminate a dialog, [accept](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdialog.html#accept) should work (at least if you've made your dialog modal, which I believe `exec_` always does).

The normal alternative is [reject](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdialog.html#reject); or, instead of either or both, you could call [done](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdialog.html#done) with an `int` parameter (which becomes `exec_`'s result).

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I think Arnold Spence found the bug.